# Error unmarshaling data '\'' looking for beginning of value Ghz to gRPC

Tags: .net-core, grpc

I have a simple gRPC service we need to  load testing and benchmarking it.
So we are testing  https://ghz.sh/docs/intro

```
service TestService {
    rpc SimpleTest (SimpleRequest) returns (SimpleReponse);
}

message SimpleRequest{
    string Name = 1;
}

message SimpleReponse{
    bool Received = 1;
}
```

I'm trying to call it with ghz
ghz --insecure --call Interface.SimpleTest -d '{"Name":"test"}' 0.0.0.0:6001
ghz --insecure --call Interface.SimpleTest -d '{"Name":"test"}' 0.0.0.0:6001

But it's always returning:

ghz: error: Error unmarshaling data ''{name:test}'': invalid character ''' looking for beginning of value.

I'm running this on windows.
.NET Core 5.

I know the service works since I used BloomRPC to try a similar call and works like a charm

Regards

J

Comment: What shell are you running this in?

Comment: usual windows command line

Comment: interesting... using powershell I can execute the line... now for a more complex object I have another error... but it's a start !, thanks @Evert

Comment: BTW I need to scape the quotation marks

Comment: Yeah thats why i asked. Different shells have different escaping rules. I don't really know the rules for either of these shells, but they would be good to learn

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Evert this was not only related to ghz nor gRPC per se.

But for everyone out there trying to parse json strings using windows command line, hope it helps.